# Hide integration test coverage per line?

Tags: sonarqube, integration-testing

I'm using SonarQube 5.1. And I only use Unit test coverage.

Is there a way in SonarQube GUI to hide the integration coverage bar in the sourceCode page at the left side, which says if this line of code is covered or not by integration test?

Comment: Do you have this feature enabled? (see http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Integration+Tests+for+Java+Project) It shouldn't be showing up unless you've specified the integration coverage report file path in the properties file..

Comment: My sonar-project property looks like this.   `sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.language=java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.projectBaseDir=xxx
sonar.junit.reportsPath=xxx
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=/jacoco.exec`

Comment: And of course the rest of the property-file `sonar.java.libraries=xxx

sonar.sources=/src

sonar.java.binaries=/class

sonar.tests=/test/src`

Comment: One reason could be that I forced the coverage value to 0 %. Key: sonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero; Could that be a reason?

Comment: Possibly, did you try analysis without setting that property?

Comment: The mentioned reason:  Key: sonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero; was the cause for shwoing the integration test coverage in the source code.

Comment: I added this as answer so that other SO users can benefit from this information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `sonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero` was set to true.

Comment: What does this mean?  How do I fix it?  I have the same question as the OP, and this answer is not terribly helpful.  I certainly have not set "sonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero" to true anywhere; I don't even know what it is.